# C# razor select2 disable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-select2

Is there a way I can set this select2 to be disable read-only if there is a value in option.AgentName? I have add the selectElement.select2 method is there anything I can add to the  callback?

> Is this the correct way to do this? using self.entry.Agent.AgentName != ""?

View

```
<div class="form-group sentence-part-container sentence-part ng-scope ui-draggable sentence-part-entry-agent sentence-part-with-select2-single" [class.has-errors]="entry.IsInvalid && entry.IsTouched">
   <div class="sentence-part-values">
       <div class="sentence-part-values-select2-single">
           <select class="form-control" style="width: 300px" [(ngModel)]="entry.Agent.VersionKey">
               <option *ngFor="let option of agents" [value]="option.VersionKey">{{option.AgentName}}</option>
           </select>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
$selectElement.select2({
   initSelection: function(element, callback) {
   console.log(self.entry.Agent.AgentName);
   if (self.entry.Agent.AgentName != "")
   {
      console.log('disabled');
      $selectElement.prop('disabled', true);
   }
       callback({ id: self.entry.Agent.VersionKey, text: self.entry.Agent.AgentName });
   },
   placeholder: "Select an agent"
})
.on("change", (e) => {
   self.ngZone.run(() => {
       self.entry.Agent.VersionKey = $selectElement.val();
       self.entry.AgentVersionKey = self.entry.Agent.VersionKey;

       let regimenEntryAgent = this.getRegimenEntryAgentByVersionKey(self.entry.Agent.VersionKey);
       if (regimenEntryAgent) {
           self.entry.Agent.AgentId = regimenEntryAgent.AgentId;
       }

       self.onSentenceChange(null);                    
   });
})
.on("select2:close", () => {
   self.entry.IsTouched = true;
   this.validate();
});
```

Comment: you want to disable it after selecting an option with option.AgentName? Or you want to disable it on page load?

Comment: In page load if there is a value in agent name

Comment: will you include the script that instantiate select2? Also will you put entry and agent model class and properties. Thanks.

Comment: @jerdine-sabio I have include the select2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to apply some logic in `newData.push()` method of `Select2`.

```
ajax: {
    url: '/DemoController/DemoAction',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            query: params.term, //search term
            page: params.page
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
        var newData = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {

            // apply some logic to the corresponding item here
            if(item.AgentName == "x"){

            }
            newData.push({
                    //id part present in data 
                    id: item.Id,     
                    //string to be displayed
                    text: item.AgentName 
            });
        });
        return { results: newData };
    },
    cache: true
},
```

***Update:*** 
It is recommended that you declare your configuration options by passing in an object when initializing Select2. However, you may also define your configuration options by using the HTML5 [data-* attributes](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes).

For the other Select2 options look [Options](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api).

Comment: Can I do anything in the option tag?

Comment: @Jefferson Please have a look at update added to the answer.

Comment: is there anything I can add in the callback?

Comment: `$selectElement.prop('disabled', true);` disables the whole control, but you need to set some options of Select2 and I think you can perform this in `processResults{}` section. If you do not have to use `Select2`, I can provide a better solution based on `DropdownList` in razor.

Comment: Yes Select2 is something that is ingrain in the application

Comment: What about applying some logic before `newData.push({})` ?